# reset_session not working in Cucumber tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd

I have the following step for a Cucumber scenario:

```
Given /^I am not logged in$/ do
  request.reset_session
  controller.instance_variable_set(:@_current_user, nil)
end
```

But when I run my Cucumber features, I get:

```
undefined method `reset_session' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

My setup:

- rails 3.0.3
- cucumber-rails 0.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cucumber is intended to exercise the full stack.  Given that, you generally don't want to muck around with the internals at a lower level as you might with rspec.

Try something like this:

```
Given /^I am not logged in$/ do
  visit logout_path
end
```

This example uses Capybara's `visit` method, so you'll need to adjust accordingly, but this should give you the right idea.